# Assignment using then function not working in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular-promise

I have below code to assign value to user using then()

```
this.userService.getUser(username).then(user => {
        console.log(user); // prints value
        this.user = user;
        console.log("after assign") 
        console.log(this.user) // assignment happens

    }, error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
    console.log(this.user) // it is undefined
```

I checked in console, the last one executes before then().

`this.userService.getUser()` return type is `Promise<User[]>`

[image: console results]

why is this happening?

TIA

Comment: your are trying to print a async data in a synchronous context

Comment: Yeah got it. I put the last line inside callback function as mentioned in the answer to question pointed to by @AJT_82